# How to copy a huge folder, skipping identical files

Tags: hard-drive, files, backup

On my main desktop I have 4 HDDs. Here is the layout:

- 60GB SSD for Linux
- 500GB HDD for Windows 10
- 2TB HDD as main storage device
- 1TB HDD as backup storage device

Every month or so, I wipe the 1TB HDD and copy all the files on the 2TB onto it, starting from fresh. My question is, **is there anyway to simply "update" the files on the 1TB HDD, since 99% of them are probably going to be the same?**

P.S. I have around 900GB of files total. It takes several hours and probably puts a substantial dent in the 1TB HDD's life copying those files...

Comment: check out `man rsync`

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks! Didn't know about this.

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like `rsync` is tailor made for your use case.

Some options I find useful are

- `--progress` which at least gives you a sense that something is happening
- `--dry-run` which does the compares but doesn't actually copy anything.  I like to do this after setting the command up to make sure I didn't mess something up.

Answer (score 3):

```
rsync --ignore-existing --recursive /src /dst
```

or manually there's the copy a given dir to another dir with if conditions adding *   ,etc but rsync should get it done.

Comment: I hope that helps you out. If so, please accept and rate. GL

Comment: `rsync --ignore-existing --recursive /src /dst`